# Open sets of $G/B$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, topological-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group and let $B$ be a Borel subgroup. What are the open sets of $G/B$? How does one define a topology on $G/B$?

Does the Bruhat decomposition of $G$ somehow induce a collection of open sets on $G/B$?

Comment: The topology is defined as one does in general for quotients of topological spaces/varieties/schemes.

Comment: The Bruhat decomposition of $G/B$ is as a disjoint union of cells, but this isn't really what you want to think about as the topology of $G/B$.

Answer (score 1):

Bruhat decomposition decomposes it as a union of subvarieties that are open in their closures; they are finitely many, exist in various dimensions, and only one of them is open (the big cell).

As $B$ is a closed subgroup there is no complication in giving a topology to $G/B$; what is important is it has a natural variety structure and is embeddable as a (closed) subvariety of a projective space. For any closed subgroup $G/H$ is embeddable as subvar of a projective space, when $H$ contains a borel subgroup the embedding is a closed embedding, hence it becomes a projective variety.